# git pre-receive hook fails to execute git commands for other repository on server

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I have a git server on my local docker, where I host 2 repositories: `main.git` and `sub.git`. `sub` is a submodule in the `main` repo. Both of them are bare. I try to add a pre-receive hook to my `main` repo, that checks if I don't reference a missing submodule revision (for example if someone forgets to push the submodule before pushing the main repo). I use this script: https://gist.github.com/T3sT3ro/902d67f29d2c913b3fef6034776777e0 which is a slightly fixed version of this one:  https://gist.github.com/bagage/bdca3d4b66d43db7a5e3.

Unfortunately, this script doesn't work. Any git command executed for the `sub` repo fails if launched from inside the `main` repo's `pre-receive` hook. When run by hand everything seems fine. For example executing `git log|show` result in `bad object HEAD` and `git branch` in `fatal: missing object 78f5da8ed1f83047d0f68fe17e5eaf86060038c3 for refs/heads/master`, even though running `git branch --contains 78f5da8ed1f83047d0f68fe17e5eaf86060038c3` by hand in `sub` repo works as it should: prints `* master`.

running `git fsck` for sub repo in hook (with debug varibles set) returns this:

```
remote: 16:45:32.575940 trace.c:318             setup: git_dir: .
remote: 16:45:32.575961 trace.c:319             setup: git_common_dir: .
remote: 16:45:32.575967 trace.c:320             setup: worktree: (null)
remote: 16:45:32.575971 trace.c:321             setup: cwd: /var/www/git/sub.git
remote: 16:45:32.575976 trace.c:322             setup: prefix: (null)
remote: 16:45:32.575982 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git fsck
remote: error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 78f5da8ed1f83047d0f68fe17e5eaf86060038c3
remote: error: refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer 78f5da8ed1f83047d0f68fe17e5eaf86060038c3
remote: notice: No default references
remote: 16:45:32.580070 read-cache.c:1925       performance: 0.000004548 s: read cache ./index
remote: 16:45:32.580107 trace.c:420             performance: 0.004374272 s: git command: git fsck
remote: dangling commit 468626a3126e8139a08727ff3c1b25f37e23f957
```

I tried changing hook's owner and group to be the same as for other files, but it doesn't work. It kinda seems like some kind of security mechanism, but on the other hand I can `touch` files in the `sub` repo. From the fsck log above we can also see that `78f5da...` is present somewhere...

repro goes like this: create main and sub repo, push some initial commits to both, add sub as submodule to main, commit on sub without pushing, in main add sub (main should now reference the local commit of sub repo), try to push main repo(fails - expected), push sub repo, try to push main repo(fails again - now with those errors).

git version on server: 2.17.1

Comment: Your sample script does not have a `git fsck` command in it. When you added it, did you also export `GIT_DIR="$url"` as the other Git commands in the script do?

Comment: yes, I tried setting GIT_DIR and even `cd`ing into the `sub` directory - still the same errors.

Comment: For `git fsck` alone that should suffice IF it's set to a full path; for some operations you need to do both. I note that the debug output says `git_dir: .` which means you would need both again. Note that it's very hard to debug a script that you're not actually showing :-)

Comment: the script is linked in gist... anyway: fixed

Comment: The gist link has no `git fsck` invocation, is all I am saying here. The trick of unsetting the local vars *for the submodule accesses only* is the way to go provided your Git has the `--local-env-vars` flag, which yours does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, git sets some environment variables, and to allow git hook to work on some other repo we need to unset some variables. Adding 
`unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)` before invoking git commands on another repo fixes the issues. I updated the gist script so it should work now. One thing left to do is check if unsetting all those variables won't break something else (for example if there are more submodules etc.)

**@EDIT**
following two lines added before invoking git commands on another repo fix this behavior. Tested for 2 submodules and many commits to be pushed at once

```
unset GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES
unset GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY
```